# Error: Member not found: 'Scrollable.maybeOf'. final scrollableState = Scrollable.maybeOf(context);

Tags: flutter

**Hello, good day everyone i encountered this error in my Android Studio Can someone help me about this i am on  Flutter 3.3.8 Thank you so much**

```
@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    final scrollableState = Scrollable.maybeOf(context);
    if (scrollableState != null) {
      // The TypeAheadField is inside a scrollable widget
      _scrollPosition = scrollableState.position;

      _scrollPosition!.removeListener(_scrollResizeListener);
      _scrollPosition!.isScrollingNotifier.addListener(_scrollResizeListener);
    }
  }
```

> /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-4.3.1/lib/src/flutter_typeahead.dart:898:40: Error: Member not found: 'Scrollable.maybeOf'.
> final scrollableState = Scrollable.maybeOf(context);
> ^^^^^^^
> /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-4.3.1/lib/src/cupertino_flutter_typeahead.dart:649:40: Error: Member not found: 'Scrollable.maybeOf'.
> final scrollableState = Scrollable.maybeOf(context);
> ^^^^^^^

I am expecting someone could help me about this flutter and my project, Ill promise after i learn coding i will payback all the help to the one in needs.!!!!

Comment: maybeOf is from 3.7.  You'll need to upgrade to 3.7, or rewrite the code to use pre-3.7 interfaces

Answer (score 10):

goto path by ctrl+click on path provided in console. change **maybeOf** to **of**. Run **`flutter pub get`** in terminal and error is gone.

Comment: Weirdly works. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

First upgrade your flutter version to latest stable running `flutter upgrade`

Then, update your `flutter_typeahead` dependency version to at least `4.3.1` on your `pubspec.yaml` file.

By the widget change log it states that this has been fixed on 28-January-2023

> PR #447 - fix: Use maybeOf for scrollable to not throw an exception in
> flutter …

See change log: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead/changelog#431---28-january-2023